# MYSQL 8.0 - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

So .. i know this might be a dumb question because it was asked and answered before but i really wanna understand everything about it.

Currently i use `docker` to build a website. In my `docker-compose` i have 2 services: `mysqldb` and `node`(which is the api).

Now.. in order to connect to my sql database using api, it takes some time so that MySql can be started up.. For that i use an `execute.sh` script that makes me able to run it manually. Beside that i have a `db_schema.js` that i run manually and it creates the tables in database.

That's how i connect:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "mysqldb",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "database",
});

connection.connect();

let createScoresTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (" +
    "team_a VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," +
    "team_a_score INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
    "team_b_score INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
    "team_b VARCHAR(100)" +
    ")"

connection.query(createScoresTable)

connection.end();
```

But as the title says, i have problem with authentication.

I know that i can do this manually by entering in database and running an `ALTER` command, but it's not so comfortable to run it everytime with every `docker-compose down` i execute..

My question is how can i fix that without using `ALTER` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your MYSQL service in docker-compose:

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I knew there was something about the plugins but i didn't have any idea on how to change this plugin. Thanks again.